# How could I do the same with Processing that this curl command does?

Tags: curl, processing

For example I've got this curl command (it is an example [Pushbullet API](https://docs.pushbullet.com/#api) request to update a list). Curl parameter "--header" is for setting the HTTP header, "-X" is for the HTTP request.

I was unable to find a solution by Googling.

> curl --header 'Access-Token: ' -X POST ICantPostMoreThanTwoLinks --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary '{"items": [{"checked": true, "text": "one"}, {"checked": true, "text": "two"}]}'

How could I do the same the curl command does in [Processing](https://processing.org/) code because I want to use Pushbullet API in Processing to display Pushbullet messages on my devices?

Comment: Crossposted: http://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/12385/using-pushbullet-api-with-processing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was answered [here](http://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/12385/using-pushbullet-api-with-processing) by koogs, many thanks to him/her for the answer.

Install the library as usual (we need the lib jars inside it).

One must add the following java code into another tab in your project called "PostRequest.java".

```
// mostly from the httprequests-for-processing library
// header support added - acd 2015-09-05

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import org.apache.http.Header;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicHeader;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class PostRequest {
  String url;
  ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
  HashMap<String, File> nameFilePairs;
  List<Header> headers;

  String content;
  String encoding;
  HttpResponse response;
  String json;

  public PostRequest(String url) {
    this(url, "ISO-8859-1");
  }

  public PostRequest(String url, String encoding) {
    this.url = url;
    this.encoding = encoding;
    nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
    nameFilePairs = new HashMap<String, File>();
    headers = new ArrayList<Header>();
  }

  public void addData(String key, String value) {
    BasicNameValuePair nvp = new BasicNameValuePair(key, value);
    nameValuePairs.add(nvp);
  }

  public void addJson(String json) {
    this.json = json;
  }

  public void addFile(String name, File f) {
    nameFilePairs.put(name, f);
  }

  public void addFile(String name, String path) {
    File f = new File(path);
    nameFilePairs.put(name, f);
  }

  public void addHeader(String name, String value) {
    headers.add(new BasicHeader(name, value));
  }

  public void send() {
    try {
      DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
      HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

      if (nameFilePairs.isEmpty()) {
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, encoding));
      } else {
        MultipartEntity mentity = new MultipartEntity();    
        Iterator<Entry<String, File>> it = nameFilePairs.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext ()) {
          Entry<String, File> pair =  it.next();
          String name = (String) pair.getKey();
          File f = (File) pair.getValue();
          mentity.addPart(name, new FileBody(f));
        }               
        for (NameValuePair nvp : nameValuePairs) {
          mentity.addPart(nvp.getName(), new StringBody(nvp.getValue()));
        }
        httpPost.setEntity(mentity);
      }

      // add the headers to the request
      if (!headers.isEmpty()) {
        for (Header header : headers) {
          httpPost.addHeader(header);
        }
      }

      // add json
      if (json != null) {
        StringEntity params =new StringEntity(json);
        httpPost.addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        httpPost.setEntity(params);
      }

      response = httpClient.execute( httpPost );
      HttpEntity   entity   = response.getEntity();
      this.content = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

      if ( entity != null ) EntityUtils.consume(entity);

      httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();

      // Clear it out for the next time
      nameValuePairs.clear();
      nameFilePairs.clear();
    } catch( Exception e ) { 
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  /*
  ** Getters
  */
  public String getContent() {
    return this.content;
  }

  public String getHeader(String name) {
    Header header = response.getFirstHeader(name);
    if (header == null) {
      return "";
    } else {
      return header.getValue();
    }
  }
}
```

Then one can then do something in your main code like

```
import http.requests.*;

void setup() {
  PostRequest post = new PostRequest(URL);
  post.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  post.addJson("{\"items\": [{\"checked\": true, \"text\": \"one\"}, {\"checked\": true, \"text\": \"two\"}]}");
  post.send();
  System.out.println("Reponse Content:" + post.getContent() + "\n");
  System.out.println("Reponse Content-Length Header: " + post.getHeader("Content-Length"));
}
```

Note the JSON has to be escaped.